# why does overload operator= makes exception safety

Tags: c++, exception

Very straight forward question.

```
class Bitmap {...};
class Widget {
    ... 
    private:
        Bitmap* pb; 
};
```

when overloaded copy assignment, the book (Effective C++) said: belowing codes are exception safety.

```
Widget& Widget::operator=(const Widget& rhs) {
    if (rhs == *this) return;
    Bitmap* pOrig = pb; //?? why remember the pb can do exception safety?
    pb = new Bitmap(*rhs.pb);
    delete pOrig;
    return *this;
  }
```

Book said : even through the new Bitmap(*rhs.pb) met the exception, the above code can do exception safety, the pb can keep the same, not pointer to the NULL？ but how， why ？ someone can help me? thanks!

Comment: Is that the exact text of the book? It doesn't sound like the kind of text that would make it through editing. Please quote the *exact text* if possible.

Comment: What kind of *exception safety*? Strong? Basic? NoExcept?

Comment: I suspect that the book says `&rhs == this`, not `rhs == *this`.

Comment: yes! It's my wrong! Thank you！

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the question might not be too precise, I think I still got the point:

Imagine, the code would have been written as follows:

```
Widget& Widget::operator=(const Widget& rhs)
{
    if (rhs == *this) // actually, you'd rather do &rhs == this!
                      // you don't want self-assignment
        return;
    delete pb;
    pb = new Bitmap(*rhs.pb);
    return *this;
}
```

What happens, if `new Bitamp()` fails with an exception - then pb is already deleted - and points to invalid memory!

So you remember first the value of pb, and if creation fails with an exception, you have not modified `this` and it remains valid *even* if an exception occured.

Answer (score 1):

If an exception is thrown during construction of `new Bitmap(*rhs.pb)`, the state of `Widget` is still unchanged.

If you simply delete `pb` before doing `new Bitmap(*rhs.pb)`:

```
Widget& Widget::operator=(const Widget& rhs) {
    if (rhs == *this) return;
    delete pb; // unsafe
    pb = new Bitmap(*rhs.pb);
    return *this;
  }
```

And `new Bitmap(*rhs.pb)` fails (throws an exception), there there is no `Bitmap` instance anymore inside `Widget`, and `pb` points to a deleted instance of `Bitmap`. This will crash during destruction of `Widget`.